# Refrencing a element that is a part of a complex type in XML Schema

Tags: xml, xsd

I have the following xml schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <xs:element name="Assignments_Hello">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>

                    <xs:element name="Student">
                        <xs:complexType >
                            <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element name="ID">
                                    <xs:simpleType>
                                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                            <xs:pattern value="[a-zA-Z0-9]{3}[0-9]"/>
                                        </xs:restriction>
                                    </xs:simpleType>
                                </xs:element>

                                <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string"  minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>

                                <xs:element name="Phone"  minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                                    <xs:simpleType>
                                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                            <xs:pattern value="[1-9][0-9]{2}-[1-9][0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}"/>
                                        </xs:restriction>
                                    </xs:simpleType>
                                </xs:element>

                            </xs:sequence>
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>

                    <xs:element name="Assignment">
                        <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:sequence>

                                <xs:element name="AssignID">
                                    <xs:simpleType>
                                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                            <xs:pattern value="[1-9]{4}"/>
                                        </xs:restriction>
                                    </xs:simpleType>
                                </xs:element>

                                <xs:element name="Topic"/>

                                <xs:element name="StudentID" type or ref =**"#----Palceholder-------#"**/>

                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I want the StudentID element under Assignment to have the type Student/ID. What do I replace the Placeholder with?
I have tried put type="Assignments_Hello/Student/ID", which didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare the type at the top level and reference it in two places:

```
<xs:simpleType name="studentIdType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="[a-zA-Z0-9]{3}[0-9]"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

 <xs:element name="Assignments_Hello">
      <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Student">
                  <xs:complexType >
                      <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element name="ID" type="studentIdType"/>
                          <!-- .... -->
                      </xs:sequence>
                  </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>

              <xs:element name="Assignment">
                  <xs:complexType>
                      <xs:sequence>
                          <!-- ... -->
                          <xs:element name="StudentID" type="studentIdType" />
```

The schema as currently written only allows for one `Student` and one `Assignment` element per `Assignments_Hello`, but if you adjusted it to allow for more than one of each, then you might want to consider using a *key* and *keyref* to ensure that student IDs are unique, and that the `StudentID` of each assignment does indeed correspond to the `ID` of one of the students.